# How to get an object out of an array without knowing its index, only 'key' name

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

With 2 arrays (one of numbers and other of objects), 
How can I get a specific object's-(`size`) value (in other function) **without knowing its index (and it's value) in the array** only its key 
with the shortest and fastest way **so I can use that value number** ?

If the array is empty except for this specific object, the `size` property value will be - 0;

If my question isn't clear please comment and I'll fix it and make it betters.

```js
let firstArray = [ 1, 2 , 10, 23, {size: 890}];
     
   funcExtract(firstArray);
    
   function funcExtract(arr){
        
    // arr ? How to find the object when knowing only its key
    }
```

**And** with array of objects

```js
let secondArray  = [ {a:2}, {b:4 },{size: 700}, {c:5} ];
 
      funcExtract(secondArray); 

      function funcExtract(arr){
        
      }
```

Comment: Please remove `reactjs` from the post tags. It's not relevant for what you're asking.

Comment: Your first array has numbers _and_ an object that has a `size` property. What is the "specific object" you're looking for? Can you give some examples?

Comment: But _what_ specific object? What is the "key" you have?

Comment: {size: 890} in this case the `key` is "size", and the `value` is 890

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function:

```js
const test = [1, 2, 3, 4, {key: 5}]
const findOne = test.find(item => item.hasOwnProperty("key"))
console.log(findOne)
```

Comment: I meant I don't need know the key's value. important

Comment: What do you mean by _knowing only its key_ then?. Updated answer, take a look

Answer (score 1):

Here's the thing which you can do it:

```js
let key = "size"
let secondArray  = [ {a:2}, {b:4 },{size: 700}, {c:5} ];
let firstArray = [ 1, 2 , 10, 23, {size: 890}];
function funcExtract(arr,key){
   let filter = arr.filter((x)=> typeof x === "object" && x.hasOwnProperty(key))
   console.log(filter[0].size)
}
funcExtract(firstArray,key);
funcExtract(secondArray,key);
```

Comment: Yes your way works, but I found here to better use the `find` method, it's a shorter way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
let secondArray  = [ {a:2}, {b:4 },{size: 700}, {c:5} ];
secondArray.find(o => o.size) // {size: 700}
a.filter(o => o.size) // good if you need to find more than 1 with same key
```

Comment: What if `o.size` is `0` (i.e. *falsey*)?

Comment: well presumably the OP can add their own safeguards, think that's out of the scope of the question

Comment: @RedBaron I updated my question, regards to size = 0

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the new question. does my answer not work? and if not, which part does not work?

Comment: @RedBaron When {size: 0} it will be > `undefined`. Than I will use `find(o => o.hasOwnProperty("size"));` Thanks